# Указатели в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, указатели

Возможно ли на Python передать в функцию указатель переменной (class 'list', либо любой другой тип) и обновить значение? Или же только путем перезаписи возможно?

Это вообще python way?

Comment: а зачем, позвольте поинтересоваться?

Comment: Непонятно что требуется. Поясните вопрос примерами кода, кодом ошибки и т.д.

Comment: Нет кода, я без понятия, возможно ли и как реализовать передачу указателя в функцию на python.

Comment: strawdog, что бы не копировать список при передаче в функцию. Ведь если в аргумент передать, то передается созданная копия.

Comment: Что не так с этим: `def f(someList):<some_job>` ?

Comment: @Victor вы о чем, что это?

Comment: Передать список в функцию можно так.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica в таком случае someList это копия списка, а не указатель. А меня интересует передача указателя на список. Вероятно, моя задумка не по python way...

Comment: Никакая не копия, а сам список:
`def f(somelist):somelist.append("hello world");list1 = [];f(list1);print(list1)` вернет `[1]`

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, спасибо, действительно так – перепроверил. Получается, для создания копии нужно вызывать .copy() ? только в этом случае будет создана копия?

Comment: Именно что. Вам ниже написали ответ.

Comment: @gohxr Вообще с копиями всё не так просто. Есть методы для глубокого копирования и для поверхностного. Поэтому уделите этому немного внимания, когда займётесь. Также стоит отметить, что операция взятия среза (даже всего списка) создаёт новый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы передать сам список:

```
some_list = [1, 2, 3]

def some_func(arg_list):
    arg_list.append(4)
    arg_list.append(5)

some_func(some_list)
print(some_list) # выведет 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

А чтобы передать копию в функцию надо использовать `copy()`

```
some_list = [1, 2, 3]

def some_func(arg_list):
    arg_list.append(4)
    arg_list.append(5)

some_func(some_list.copy())
print(some_list) # 1, 2, 3
```